# For a, b in c, d Python

Tags: python, loops, dictionary, for-loop

I have a list of keys and a list of values, I want to fill a dictionary so like:

```
 for key, value in listKeys, listValues:
     dict[key] = value
```

However, I get the following error:

```
builtins.ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

Answer (score 8):

You want [the `zip` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#zip) to make a generator of `tuple`s of values from each of a number of inputs:

```
mydict = {}
for key, value in zip(listKeys, listValues):
     mydict[key] = value
```

That said, you could skip the rigmarole of writing your own loop and let the `dict` constructor do the work; it can take an iterable of key/value pairs to initialize itself, and avoid the Python level loop entirely:

```
mydict = dict(zip(listKeys, listValues))
```

or if `mydict` is an existing non-empty `dict`, use the `update` method, which accepts the same arguments as the constructor:

```
mydict.update(zip(listKeys, listValues))
```

Side-note: I renamed your variable to `mydict`, because shadowing built-in names like `dict` is a terrible, terrible idea.

Comment: thanks, i appreciate the quick response

Comment: If you see a very common question with a popular canonical duplicate, you can vote or flag the question for closure with that duplicate.

Answer (score 2):

Iterate through two lists simultaneously using `zip` :

```
for key, value in zip(listKeys, listValues) :
    dict[key] = value
```

Comment: thanks, i appreciate the quick response

Comment: If you see a very common question with a popular canonical duplicate, you can vote or flag the question for closure with that duplicate.

Comment: Why a down-vote ?! My reputation is not enough to do this, and down-voting is no way to give this information, a single comment is enough. Please lift the down-vote. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: You can flag a question for closure as a duplicate [with 15 reputation](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts).

Comment: Thanks for this info, but my point is down-voting others' answer just to "punish" them for not knowing this info, is not OKAY. We all are learners here. @TigerhawkT3

Comment: Yes, it looks like someone downvoted your answer. Whoever did so must have felt that it wasn't useful (as suggested by the tooltip). However, votes are anonymous, so we may never know who voted this way.

Answer (score 1):

Use zip:

`for key, value in zip(listKeys, listValues): dict[key] = value`

Comment: thanks, i appreciate the quick response

Comment: If you see a very common question with a popular canonical duplicate, you can vote or flag the question for closure with that duplicate.